# Backup script that can reboot to another os, run backup and boot back

Tags: rsync

My computer has two disks: sda with Primary Ubuntu and sdb with Helper Ubuntu with Clonezilla installed. 
On Windows it is easy to create an incremental backup thanks to shadow copy. On Ubuntu I have to do these steps:

Boot to Clonezilla
Mount sda
clone sda to /path/to/packups/$date.img
Reboot back to Primary Ubuntu

I am trying to automate this process with two scripts.
Script on Primary Ubuntu:

(1) rename current grub to grub.orig
(2) copy grub.boot_sdb grub
(3) update-grub
(4) reboot

Script on Helper Ubuntu

(1) delete grub
(2) copy grub.boot_sda grub
(3) update-grub
(4) On startup do backup

```
  (4a) Using Clonezilla       

  (4b) DIY script that 
      computes and saves each file's checksum
      for each file with new checksum:
           saves file in /path/to/backup/$DATE/path/to/file
```

(5) reboot

Questions:
Is there a sync tool that can do incremental backups of the OS disk on Ubuntu?
Will (4b) approach break anything? For example, will it handle links correctly?